# How to add a new value to an existing class instance in Python?

Tags: python, list, class

I am trying to add a new value to an existing class instance, but I fail. I will directly explain what I am trying to do and will show my code:

Let's say I have a number of people with different names and they have subjects with different value. The input should look like this:

```
Joe -> car -> 5000
Mike -> house -> 100000
John -> phone -> 1000
Joe -> house -> 80000
etc.
```

When I get an input with the same name, I should append the new subject to the existing one and make a list from all the subjects and adding the two values.
At the end, when I get an input:

```
Joe vs John
```

I should compare them only if they have at least one subject from the same category (in this example it will be "house") and this continues till I get the command "Stop".

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, subject, price):
        self.name = name
        self.subject = subject
        self.price = price

people_list = []

while True:
    data_input = input().split(" -> ")

    if data_input[0] == "Stop":
        break

    elif len(data_input) == 3:
        name, subject, price = data_input[0], data_input[1], data_input[2]
        same_name = [x for x in people_list if x.name == name]
        if len(same_name)>0:

            (......)

        else:
            person = Person(name, subject, price)
            people_list.append(person)


    else:
        info = data_input[0].split()
        name_1, name_2 = info[0], info[2]
        ....
```

Therefore I have 3 questions:

1. Can I add the new subject and its value somehow in the class directly? This would create one list with all the subjects and one list with all the prices for each name in the class, right?
2. If this is not possible, can I somehow append the new subjects in the list (people_list in this example)? I think this is not possible or if possible, then much more complicated.
3. How can I search in the class without using list comprehension?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your definition of `Person` suggests that an instance has exactly one subject and one price member.  It sounds like what you want is for each Person to have multiple unique prices indexed by subject.  That sounds like a `dict` to me.  Perhaps a different implementation would solve this for you?

Comment: Two things off the top of my head would be a) to overload the `__eq__` operator to check equality based on subject, or b) (much preferred) to have a dict of all possible subjects populated with empty lists for the values, and a method to update them and access the dict by subject key, rather than by self.subject

Comment: Yep, I also thought so and tried it with nested dicts, but then I got stuck when I have to compare two people. I structured it so: 
```
{'Name1': {'Subject1': 'Price1'}, 'Name2': {'Subject1': 'Price1'}, 'Name3': {'Subject1': 'Price1', 'Subject2': 'Price2', 'Subject3': 'Price3'}}
```
I first should check whether they have the same subject  and if yes, I have to sum all the prices and then compare who has "more money" (in other words). And somewhere here I can not extract the values, perform the check and compare correctly.